# Android animation shows blank view when reverse animation added

Tags: android, android-animation

I have made animation through xml like rotation animation which is to be used for activity transition. the first part is the rotate and scale animation which work togather to show half rotation the work fine but when i add reverse of them with start offset they are showing blank view instead of animation... not showing even the first part of animation which was working correctly..

Here is xml code when only first part was there and it is working correctly..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<rotate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="-15"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />

<scale
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:toYScale="1" />


</set>
```

but when i add reverse code it just goes blank all the time...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<rotate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="-15"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />

<scale
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:toYScale="1" />


 <rotate
    android:startOffset="2000"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromDegrees="-15"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />

  <scale
    android:startOffset="2000"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1" />


  </set>
```

so guys please tell me where i'm going wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to dublicate your animations to achieve reverse effect. You can use [android:repeateMode = "reverse"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android%3arepeatMode) and [android:repeatCount = "1"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android%3arepeatCount)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<rotate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="-15" />


<scale
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:toYScale="1" />

</set>
```

You need to set `repeatCount` and `repeatMode` both for `scale` and `rotate` animations. Unfortunately you can't just use it directly in `set` attribute due [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17662) in `AnimationSet` implementation.

But this animation will be applied only on one activity. If you actually want the first activity to disappear and then the second activity to appear you need to split your animation into two pieces. The first part will have your `rotate` and `scale` direct animations and the second part will have reversed `rotate` and `scale` animation. So basically just you need to split your `set` with four animation into two files. Then you need to use this two animations for starting new activity:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.direct, R.anim.reversed);
```

Comment: Andrei thanks for your answer the first suggestion of reverse doesn't work for me because i want mirror kind of reverse means mirror effect and secondly i know in overridePendingTransition we give separate files but i was combining the animation to view the complete flow by applying on single element... so in my question i doesn't asked the other ways to do what i want i asked why my code is not working ? and where is problem in my code..

Comment: Your xml is ok but there is a bug in AnimationSet. `android:startOffset` doesn't work from xml properly. You got a blank screen because all 4 animations are running simultaneously.